# What is the meaning of the configuration item "arbitrator" in the TDengine's configuration file taos.cfg?

Tags: database, tdengine

What is the meaning of the configuration item "arbitrator" in the TDengine's configuration file taos.cfg?
Participate in the leader election as a voter, but not become the leader?
Can TDengine work with two nodes?

Answer (score 0):

`If the number of replicas is even, it is impossible to elect a master from a vnode group when half of the vnodes are not working. Similarly, when half of the mnodes are not working, the master of the mnode cannot be elected because of the "split brain" problem. To solve this problem, TDengine introduced the concept of Arbitrator. Arbitrator simulates a vnode or mnode working, but is simply responsible for networking, and does not handle any data insertion or access. As long as more than half of the vnodes or mnodes, including the Arbitrator, work, the vnode group or mnode group can normally provide data insertion or query services. For example, in the case of 2 replicas, if one node A is offline, but the other node B is normal on and can connect to the Arbitrator, then node B can work normally.`